# How do I use the PHP Sass processsor in the Omega 5 Drupal theme?

Tags: drupal, sass, drupal-7, drupal-theming

It appears that Omega 5 includes a PHP based Sass compiler (phamlp) in the theme.  When I upload a sass file into my sub-theme, it does not get compiled.  How do I tell Drupal/Omega5/phamlp to compile Sass into CSS?

I can find no documentation on the Drupal site for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  Edit the .info file to remove the line

```
stylesheets[all][] = style/css/base/site-branding.css
```

and add the line

```
stylesheets[all][] = style/scss/base/site-branding.scss
```

The system will now automatically process that .scss file.  You can also add in any other .sass or .scss files in the same way.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how or if the <code>@import</code> function works. Would be good to be able to stack up all the processed scss files into one file that is called through the theme (like what Omega4 does).